# Problem when using \LaTeX \includegraphics with some PDF files

Tags: pdf, latex, include

I noticed some strange effects when including existing pdf graphics in my laTeX documents:

Most file work flawlessly, but some PDFs that were created on a different machine (or from the web) cause the whole page on which they are embedded to become ever-so-slightly distorted. I only notice the difference in a side-by-side comparison, but once you see it, it's obvious. The text layout seems slightly broken, and when you zoom in you can see it better.

I will try to make some screenshots to further elaborate, but in the meantime:

Has anyone seen this before and how can I get rid of these distortions?

Comment: how is the quality of the pdf graphics before you insert them into your document? 

And what PDF viewer are you using? I've seen distortion from the PDF viewer I often use (Sumatra PDF), but when the same PDF is opened in reader or printed, it looks fine.

Comment: When you zoom in on the "broken" pages, do the letters break up into pixels? And how about on the normal pages?

My first guess is that your PDF graphics are mostly vector format and the "odd" ones are rasterized. This may be cause the PDF you are producing to switch from vector to raster format for those pages that have rasterized graphics. It should be pretty evident at high zoom levels if this is the case.

Comment: print the pages - maybe the problem is with your viewer.

Comment: unfortunately, I could not find a pdf that produces the error since posting. I had one case where a similar effect showed up, but it disappeared when printing. I will keep looking, perhaps I can find it again...

Comment: The viewer used is Adobe Acrobat Pro, on Windows.

Comment: I have the same problem with a PDF produced with pdflatex (MiKTeX 2.9) and viewed with Acrobat Reader X or other viewers -- one page comes out weird. When zooming in the letters do not break up into pixels. Interesting when converting to postscript from GSview 4.9 (resolution 600): pswrite produces a file which is ugly (pixeled) except for said page, whereas ps2write does the opposite: the said page is the only nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I had one case where a similar effect showed up, but it disappeared when printing.*

Almost certainly, Mica is right, and this is a PDF viewer problem.

A guess: if the problem is with lettering (distorted or missing letters and symbols), this could be a problem with non-embedded fonts, where your PDF viewer is making bad substitutions for the fonts in the document.  The first place to look is at the list of fonts in the document, then at what your viewer will look for to use when it renders the document.  It could be that you have fonts that your PDF viewer isn't finding.

Comment: It looks like it is not a viewer problem: the problem with such a page remains when converting to postscript.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen the content of a PDF affect the layout of the text *outside* the PDF.
If you are using `pdflatex` I suggest you try regular latex and convert the external PDFs to EPS files using `pdf2ps` and `ps2epsi` (at least on a Unix machine these commands ship as part of Ghostscript).

If you are not using `pdflatex`, what are you using to *display* the results that shows the distortion?

Comment: I assume he's talking about the typesetting instead of the layout (see comment about zooming in). If you compare otherwise identical vector and raster PDF's on your screen, the rasterized file may be subject to different anti-aliasing than the vector file. The issue is not visible in the printed PDFs, and is viewer / platform dependent.

Comment: Yeah, it looks to me like a different anti-aliasing. If it only shows up in the viewer, not in the printout, then I will try to live with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem might be related to the one reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169041/font-problem-when-editing-tex-produced-pdf-in-external-software). My workaround is to open the files in inkscape and when saving as pdf render fonts as paths (a tickbox option).